# Retrieve Data from USB Device

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I know this is sort of a "Help me with my code" kind of website, but I could actually use a little help with just methodology.

I am looking to retrieve data from a USB device, this device is a fingerprint scanner.  Because I bought it online and wasn't reading carefully enough, drivers and other installation programs weren't included.  Send it back?  Nah . . .

I want to see if it is possible to retrieve data from this device.  To be honest, I don't even know if it's possible, but I would love to give it a whack.

I looked into making INF files and things Microsoft has put out, but I honestly don't know where to start simply because I have absolutely no experience doing this. I have a lot of a program set up to organize the data and such, just need to find a way to actually get it.

What should I research and look into?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting my reading [USB Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931448086). The first few chapters will give you a good overview of how USB works. This will give you a basic understanding of the protocol, types of transfers, descriptors and general usage of a device. You need this knowledge and terminology so you can understand the rest of the documentation below.

From there you will probably want to use [WinUSB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) to interface with the device. If the device is vendor specific then WinUSB is the best bet. If the device enumerates as an HID device then you won't need a kernel driver but you will need to interface with the hidapi to interface with the device. You can discover this by looking at the descriptors through some tool like UVCView.exe, or looking to see if the HID driver is loaded in Device Manager (if it's not you will probably have an unidentified device).